# How to make calculator round to nearest tenth

Tags: android, calculator

I am building a calculator but when you start with decimals it won't round to the nearest tenth like I want it to. Anyone's help would be greatly appreciated.  https://fuzzyandroidblog.wordpress.com/  I added it here wouldn't let me post for some reason thanks for help

Comment: Can you show some code to see if theres a problem within the code or missing bits

Comment: https://fuzzyandroidblog.wordpress.com/  I added it here wouldn't let me post for some reason thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`NumberFormat`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/NumberFormat.html) with maximum fraction digits of 1 to format a floating point value to a string representation with at most one number after the decimal point.

Comment: Could you give me a code example or look at mine and see if you can tell where I went wrong