# How to build calculator to round

Tags: android, calculator

I am trying to make my calculator round to nearest tenth can anyone help here is my code https://fuzzyandroidblog.wordpress.com

Comment: [This is a duplicate of the other question you posted.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27422365/how-to-make-calculator-round-to-nearest-tenth)

Answer (score 0):

To round `float unroundedValue` to the nearest one-tenth, do this:

```
float roundedValue = Math.round(unroundedValue * 10.0) / 10.0;
```

When you display the `roundedValue` you will still have to specify the format with one decimal place.

```
String.format("%.1f", roundedValue)
```